# Is there any difference in meaning in "Among people, there is understanding & 2.There is understanding among them?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

> 1. Among people, there is understanding.
> 2. There is understanding among them.

Are they two correct sentences? Is there any difference in meaning?

---

3.**Whether there is understanding among them would require a further prove**

Here, is "among them" an adjectival prepositional phrase modifying the word *understanding* (gerun acting as noun) or an adverbial prepositional phrase modifying *IS* (linking verb)?

Can prepositional phrase modify linking verb like "is, feel etc."?

Comment: First of all, the second sentence doesn't specify *people*. That alone is a big difference.

Comment: I would argue that neither of these is really a complete sentence.
The first feels awkward as it stands, and the plural is almost certainly not needed.

Comment: What are you actually trying to say with that sentence? I have some ideas of better words, but I am not sure what you actually need.